# Hibernate criteria query on two unrelated or non-associated tables

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria

I am a new-born infant to Hibernate. I have come across a SQL where I need to Join 3 tables where 2 tables are not related to each other. My first doubt is, is it possible to join non-associated tables using Criteria? If yes, How can I achieve it?

The SQL query is as follows

```
Select a.des from AAA.a,AAA.b,AAA.c where a.cde=c.cde and a.type_id=b.type_id and b.type_des="WWW" order by c.create_Time DESC;
```

Here, no association or relation exist between table `a` and table `c`. But many to one relation exist between table `a` and table `b`.

The main condition is that I need to use Criteria for this SQL.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Criteria queries only have one root entity, and can join to other entities via their associations. There is no reason to use Criteria for such a static query. Use HQL.

Comment: So you mean that Criteria needs some association to exist between the given tables?

Comment: No. I mean that if you select from **entity** A, and you want to join with **entity** B, then an association must exist between **entity** A and **entity** B.